# Applescript Notifications with Buttons

Tags: terminal, applescript

Notification Alerts are fairly easy to program in Applescript:
`osascript -e 'display notification "notification text content" with title "Alert!" sound name "Purr"'`.

However i am yet to find an internet page or StackOverflow question which explains how to program them with buttons, similar to the type which appears when the App Store pesters you to upgrade to OS X Yosemite. In addition, the syntax would be used through the command `osascript -e`.

**How do i program an Applescript alert through the notification centre with buttons?**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5):

The `display notification` command of Standard Additions provides only the parameters `sound name`, `subtitle`, `with title` and the body of the notification as direct parameter because it's not possible to handle the callbacks when the user presses a button in the AppleScript runner environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Preferences > Notifications, and scroll the applications to find the application `Script Editor` which is the application that sends the notification when you execute `osascript -e '...'`. Select `Alerts` as the alert style and you are all set!

Comment: thank you so much, this is what I was looking for! had set the application to use alerts in notification center, but because it uses script editor to send automation notifications I couldn't understand why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is pretty clear [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/DisplayNotifications.html)

> Notifications are shown as alerts or banners, depending on the user’s settings in System Preferences > Notifications

But it doesn't provide an example code to catch the button clicked. (if you try it just opens the applescript editor)